# Do Sell-Side Platforms (SSP) like Admeld or PubMatic cover premium ad inventory selling for publishers?

Tags: advertising

Large companies may/may not hire a sales force to sell premium ads. But, for medium or small websites, how do they handle the premium ad inventory with maximum values? What are all available paths to sell their ads?